# How do I disable the dynamic contrast (aka auto exposure)?

Tags: control

Control has a feature where if you stare into something bright, everything else around it becomes dark; and if you stare into something dark, everything else around it becomes bright, mimicking the way our eyes work.

Unreal Engine games do the same thing, and I can usually stand it there.  But in Control the effect is *REALLY* pronounced.  When I'm running through a hallway, the brightness dips up and down a lot as I pass by lights, making the game look like a rave.

**Is there any way to disable this effect?**

Comment: Is there a HDR setting anywhere? I've seen it called that in other games (HL2). (Also have a look for *Bloom* settings as that can also create weird lighting)